# What workflow design pattern should I use for a sequence of process that requires user input?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, workflow, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

I am developing an application where the users can execute tasks / workflows. Each task is made up of a sequence of of actions to be executed. I want to be able to be able to have user input after the workflow is started.

Example:

Task starts
Action1 starts
Action1 ends
Action2 starts
Action2 ends
Action3 needs user input (UI opens window to get user input)
Action3 gets user input
Action3 starts
Action3 ends
Task ends
I am developing this i C# and I am aware of Workflow Foundation and tasks in C#. They may have what I need, but I am also interested in hearing about a design pattern for doing this from scratch.

Comment: This is similar to your previously asked question that was closed.

Comment: It's barely on topic, but it's still too broad.  We can't answer this for you.  What you need to do is what we all do in this case: 1) research frameworks 2) select ones that appear to be good candidates 3) prototype these as well as a hand-written solution 4) use this practical experience to decide on one.